# frozen graph.pb to tflite for running on Google coral (input and output array missing)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, google-coral, tensorflow-lite

I have created a TensorFlow model in the format was frozen graph.pb and I want to run it on a Rasberry Pi with a google coral, so I try to convert it using this code:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
        graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I run it on google collab but I don't know how I should use for input and output array, [this is the model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BkTj1IxyoBslqf93EkeDpW7BufM3ngVv).